# Rails ROO Gem Excel upload validate file extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spreadsheet, roo

The code below checks and raises a Run Time error for unknown file formats.

```
def open_spreadsheet
    case File.extname(file.original_filename)
        when ".csv" then CSV.new(file.path)
        when ".xls" then Roo::Excel.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
        when ".xlsx" then Roo::Excelx.new(file.path)
    else 
        raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
    end
end
```

I want to show the error message rather than runtime error.

```
attr_accessor :file
```

How can I validate the uploaded spreadsheet header field and show the error message if there is any modification in header from standard format?

Comment: You want to validate the file extension when the user uploads the file. The implementation depends a bit on your controller, model, and library you use for uploads. [Carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#securing-uploads) for example allows you to define a `extension_whitelist`. If the extension doesn't match the list, the validations fail and the user should see an error.

Comment: I used accept attributes to accept xls and xlsx for now.

Comment: How do i validate the headers value

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
def open_spreadsheet
    case File.extname self.file.original_filename
    when ".xls"
        Roo::Excel.new self.file.path
    when ".xlsx"
        Roo::Excelx.new self.file.path
    else
        self.errors[:file] << I18n.t("errors.messages.invalid_file_format", extension: File.extname(file.original_filename))
        return nil
    end
end
```

You could hard-code the message there, but is nice to have it in the correct I18n tag

Comment: It doesn't show the error message and it doesn't validate the extensions too.

Comment: How to validate the headers of the sheet?